# Feature request: Stacking bounties

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to see a way to be able to stack bounties. Say Joe shmo has a question out there and someone puts a bounty on it for 50 points. Well lets say I like Joe's question and I also want to know the answer. I would like to be able to add my 2 cents to the bounty.

The question that really spurred this was this one.[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/556490/how-to-help-a-computer-user-who-has-parkinsons-disease/556525#556525)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I'm really hoping to see this put through

Comment: I've run in to this before myself. +50? Pssh. C'mon. :P Let me take it to +200. Can anyone think of potential problems? I see no problem allowing each user to assign their bounties themselves, no problem with multiple bounty timers, and I can't think of a way this could be abused. Multiple bounties are already allowed, just not concurrent bounties. Why?

Comment: You actually brought up a good point. How are the timers going to work? You could do a good deal of things. You could have it where another bounty "renews" the old bounty. You could also have it with multiple timers like you said. Or you could have it where your bounty lasts only as long as the original bounty does.

Comment: They can simply decide on a way. None of the ways seem to drastically effect it's use.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this without causing problems is to provide for multiple, separate bounties on a single question.  Each bounty will run separately and will be controlled by their respective users.  This ensures that concurrent bounties don't conflict with each other.  Some limits need to be imposed, though:

- The total reputation offered by concurrent bounties should not be allowed to exceed a value like +750.
- There must not be more than three bounties at any given time on a question.
- It may be necessary to combine the post notices for each bounty together to prevent post notices from taking up an excessive amount of space between the question and the answer area.  The text specific to each bounty may have to be hidden behind a "show details" link to avoid clutter.